# Unit Test Method\Test Count

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I have a series of unit tests to validate structure in my ORM domain model.  The first test counts the number of entities in the metadata, so lets say 146 Entities.

This means I then need 146 unit tests to validate the `property\collection` names.

My PROBLEM is that I need a test to test the tests :)

Is there a way to validate the entity count == test method count (where name begins with X as there's many methods in the class)

Comment: You should focus on [unit test coverage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx) rather than the number of tests.

Comment: So you want to make sure that you have one test per entity?  A good test runner will tell you how many tests you have in a test set - would that not answer the need?

Comment: Why do you need to test name of each property/collection? That sounds like a very fragile test that is too tied to implementation.

Comment: @Branislav ...yes...it sucks :)  But the problem is that the entity doesn't persist its state when you remove it from the model and re-add it.  So we need a way to check to make sure when it comes back it's namespace and casing is the same as it was.  The WebApps would be fine, they wouldn't compile...but the legacy WebSites with hundreds of random pages, we just can't test them all, and the site isn't buildable to begin with.
Yeah I guess I could extract these out to their own class then just look.

Comment: The problem for me comes in where there's 146 tests, 142 entities...which are missing

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question you're looking to validate that you have written a test for each Entity in your ORM solution. Specifically, you're assuming that if there are 146 entities you should have 146 corresponding tests. Effectively you want to assert you have authored the correct number of tests.

The most obvious solution would be to use reflection on the test assembly and extract the tests you're looking for. There are many simple things you could do here, including building a hashset of entities and identifying test fixtures using a naming convention or a custom attribute that you define.

However, having faced a similar problem before perhaps a more elegant solution would be to use some custom test framework code that tests the Entities using meta-data and reflection. The same "how to test the tests" problem arises here too, but can be mitigated by writing a few tests that demonstrate that the long-hand form tests and custom test framework accomplish the same result. If you can prove your automation is sound then your maintenance concern for the tests no longer becomes an issue. Another advantage point is that you can randomize the test data and uncover unexpected problems in the entities if the tests run frequently.